# Writing to a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to retrieve all iOS events, from all calendars, with a predefined location string of "Office", then write the result to the NSLog and a UITextView.

Here is my code thus far:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    @synthesize eventStore = _eventStore;
    @synthesize events     = _events;
    @synthesize eventTextView;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        // Store a reference to the event store
        EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

       [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted,            
    NSError *error) {
                // handle access here
            if (granted)
                NSLog (@"Access granted");
        }];
        self.eventStore = eventStore;

        // Define a range of event dates we want to display

        NSDate *startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(-1*60*60)]; // 1 hour in  

    the past
        NSDate *endDate   = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(60*60*24*365)]; // 1 year  

    from now

        // Create a predicate to search all celndars with our date range

        NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
        endDate:endDate calendars:nil];


        // Query the event store using the predicate.

        NSArray *results       = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

        //Convert the results to a mutable array and store so we can implement swipe to 

    delete

        NSMutableArray *events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:results];
        self.events = events;


        // Load the events from the event store
        //[self reloadEvents:nil];

        [super viewDidLoad];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (void) reloadEvents:(id)sender
    {
   }

    - (IBAction)getEvents:(id)sender {

        int i;
        int eventCount;

        eventCount = [self.events count];

        for (i = 0; i < eventCount; i++){

            self.eventTextView.text = [[self.events objectAtIndex: i]title], [[self.events 

    objectAtIndex: i]startDate], [[self.events objectAtIndex: i]endDate], [[self.events     

    objectAtIndex: i]location];


            NSLog (@"Event Title: %@, Event Start Date: %@, Event End Date: %@, Event 

    Location: %@",[[self.events objectAtIndex: i]title],
                [[self.events objectAtIndex: i]startDate],
                [[self.events objectAtIndex: i]endDate],
                [[self.events objectAtIndex: i]location]);
        }

    }
    @end
```

**The result in the UITextView "eventTextView", is that l just get my last event title and nothing else, but in my console l get everything that l have asked for. Am l going about this in the right way?**

Also, l gather that you can subscribe to the event store for notifications / changes to the calendar/s? How would this work in the context of the above? I am assuming that this would take the place of the button action, especially if the application was set to enter the background?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
self.eventTextView.text = [[self.events objectAtIndex: i]title], [[self.events 
objectAtIndex: i]startDate], [[self.events objectAtIndex: i]endDate], [[self.events     
objectAtIndex: i]location];
```

Notice that you're *replacing* the content of the UITextView every iteration of the loop. What you intended was concatenation, which in Objective-C is best handled by creating an `NSMutableString` and calling the `appendString` method on it.

Outside of loop:

```
NSMutableString *textVal = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Inside your loop:

```
[textVal appendString:[[self.events objectAtIndex: i]title], [[self.events 
objectAtIndex: i]startDate], [[self.events objectAtIndex: i]endDate], [[self.events     
objectAtIndex: i]location]];
```

After loop:

```
self.eventTextView.text = [NSString stringWithString:textVal];
```

Comment: Thank you Austin, l have now converted the NSDate elements from my array, to a string using a NSDate formatter, and then implemented your above solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're over-writing the text in the UITextfield  with each cycle of the for loop, hence why you're only getting the last one.

Furthermore, only the event title is showing as it's a string, the rest I suspect, are not strings (being a mixture of NSDates, etc) and  and need to be converted to a string for display in the UITextfield.